How is a deceased beneficiary handled in Japan if a will doesn't specify?
Presume that a notary deed will in Japan provides equal shares of the estate to three beneficiaries, all Japanese citizens, and does not specify what happens if a beneficiary dies before the testator. If that does happen, how is that handled? I haven't been able to find any discussion of this in English.
I know how the statutory division works if there is no will. What happens if there is a will and a beneficiary has died?

Is the share divided between the remaining beneficiaries?
Does the share go to the deceased beneficiary's heirs?
Does the family court makes a case by case decision, and if so, on what grounds?
Something else?

Edit: I found this on Reddit /r/JapanFinance:

It's also worth noting that heirs of heirs do not automatically inherit inheritance rights. In other words, if you designate John Smith, of X address, as an heir, and John Smith dies before you, John Smith's heirs will not be able to claim John Smith's portion of your estate. Instead, the part of your will referencing John Smith will be invalid, because it references a non-existent person.

I don't know the poster's qualifications, but they are a moderator of the JapanFinance subreddit.

The relevant substantive law
The exact language of the will is likely to be very important in this case. Subtle differences in exactly how the gift is phrased are likely to be determinative and could lead to different outcomes. Because fine shades of meaning in a will is important and because the will is most likely drafted in a very particular legalistic way by a legally trained Japanese notary, this should be evaluated by a legally trained native speaker of Japanese, before assuming that the meaning is clear based upon a reading by a non-legally trained person or a person who is not a native speaker of the Japanese language.
Succession to property at death in Japan, with or without a will, is governed by Part V of the Japanese Civil Code. Wills, in turn, are governed by Chapter VII of that part of the Japanese Civil Code.
The main provision of the Japanese Civil Code relevant to this question are Articles 988 and 994, and 995, which have been translated into English at the link above. In this English translation they say:

Article 988
If a legatee dies without accepting or renouncing a legacy, the
legatee's heir may accept or renounce the legacy within the scope of
the heir's own right of inheritance; provided, however, that if the
testator manifests different intention by will, that intention
prevails. . . .
Article 994
(1)A legacy does not become effective if the legatee predeceases the
testator.
(2)The preceding paragraph also applies in respect of a legacy that is
subject to a condition precedent, if the legatee dies before the
fulfillment of the condition; provided, however, that if the testator
manifests different intention by will, that intention prevails.
Article 995
If the effect of a legacy does not arise, or if its effect is lost due
to renunciation, that which the legatee would have received devolves
to the heirs; provided, however, that if the testator manifests a
different intention by will, that intention prevails.

Thus, while the descendants of the deceased heir take the share of the deceased heir in intestate succession cases (i.e. when there is not a will), the language of the will would control when there is will. But if the will is silent on a question of who inherits if a beneficiary of the will dies, Japan's civil code provides that the share a deceased beneficiary under a will who predeceases a decedent will pass to that predeceased beneficiary's heirs.
The answer is also complicated, however, by the fact that the authority to direct who receives your inheritance is strongly constrained by law in Japan. Certain groups of relatives cannot be arbitrarily disinherited the way that they can be in the common law countries. If a reading of the will leads to a distribution which is contrary to these mandatory inheritance rules, those provisions of the will are invalid.
The answer from Reddit quoted in the question is, at a minimum, misleading. It is more wrong than right, under my reading of the relevant provision of the Japanese Civil Code quoted above. One could reach the interpretation provided by the Reddit commentator by looking at Japanese Civil Code Article 994 in isolation. But, when you also consider Japanese Civil Code Articles 988 and 995, and read the three relevant provisions together as a whole (as one should when interpreting a comprehensive civil code like Japan's), the interpretation provided by the Reddit commentator is not a fair reading of what the Japanese Civil Code says on the subject.
The process by which the question is resolved
A notary public, i.e. a koshonin (交渉人), who in Japan is a highly trained legal professional, drafts the notarial will and has custody of it prior to the decedent's death (sometimes after preparing for the meeting with the notary with a gyosei shoshi, described below).
But normally the survivors of the decedent administer the will via what is called "universal succession" without the involvement of a court or a notary. Instead, estate administration is carried out under the direction of an heir designated in the will, sometimes with the help of a gyosei shoshi (行政書士), a term sometimes translated as an "Administrative scrivener" but perhaps better described as an independent paralegal or legal technician (who does not have the depth of legal training of an English solicitor), or in much more complex cases for much higher fees, with the guidance of an actual Japanese lawyer (a position somewhat akin to a British barrister) called a bengoshi (弁護士).
Ambiguities or different possible ways to divide a decedent's assets are supposed to be resolved by a mutual agreement of their heirs, if possible. But if the heirs need guidance, they would often turn to a notary public or attorney for guidance before resorting to the courts to resolve an estate administration dispute. If the heirs cannot agree, mediation, if possible, or a family court case, if not, would resolve the issue.
